How to find CPMM pool address on Solana Explorer create tx
I created a CPMM liquidity pool using the @raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2 and a JS script but forgot to print out the poolId,
How can I fetch this from the explorer.

On explorers that have named accounts used in a transaction, for example, on the Solana explorer, the pool address will be the poolState account.
You will find this in the initialize instruction because you are creating a pool.
Using this tx as an example -> https://explorer.solana.com/tx/zzHTm126wfKDLSb7ALWEW4EwW2oKRiA3BrBJfEECWA4Jjsb9VVZV5sAKq5QSgTjUfUgRuqDRUjc6255CiVPCdjT?cluster=devnet

